# What sun-like star is closest to earth/sun?

Tags: star

This [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nearest_stars_and_brown_dwarfs) says that Tau Ceti is very like the Sun (spectrally). Others are predominantly red dwarfs.

Is Tau Ceti closest star which is quite like the sun according to some criteria?

Comment: I think you missed alpha centauri A. It's on the list, closer than tau ceti and more sun like

Comment: You need to define the criteria, otherwise this question is primarily opinion. However Wikipedia has a list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_analog

Comment: Unless the binary system is disqualified, both Alpha Centauri A and B are somewhat sun-like.

Answer (score 1):

> According to their system of classification, the Sun is known as a yellow dwarf star. This group of stars are relatively small, containing between 80% and 100% the mass of the Sun. So the Sun is at the higher end of this group. The official designation is as a G 2V star.

<sub>(by Fraser Cain)</sub>

> Is Tau Ceti closest star which is quite like the sun according to some criteria?

No,Tau Ceti's stellar class is G 8Vp.

The closest star bearing our Sun's stellar class is Alpha Centauri A (HD 128620)

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out by @JamesK in a comment, one has to define how similar to the sun your star should be.

If you want only the same spectral class, then Alpha Centauri A is your pick.

If it should be a [solar analog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_analog), it has to have similar spectral class, and similar amount of [heavy elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallicity) and a similar planetary system (as far as is possible to detect at the moment, which is not very).
Going with this an reading off-of the wikipedia list, your pick would then be [Sigma Draconis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_Draconis).

Then, there's a even stricter class of similarity, namely the solar twin. Those aren't exact twins, as no such thing has been found to date. But by all other relevant parameters, particularly the spectroscopically determined element abundances, they're very much like the sun.
Here the closest one would be [18 Scorpii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/18_Scorpii).

> Is Tau Ceti closest star which is quite like the sun according to some criteria?

So you see, here you can pick your criteria and choose your closest star according to those.